# Create a data extension with the number of clicks and opened emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I'm working on a feature for marketing cloud and I need to create a Data Extension with those fields : NumberOfOpenMails,NumberOfClicks and all the other fields relative to the subscriber. I found that I could do some SOQL query to find this with AutomationStudio but as I'm a beginner, I don't quite understand all. I found this [example of query](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_query_find_subscribers_with_no_opens_or_clicks_ref.htm&type=5) that retrieve subscribers with No Opens or Clicks. Here is the code used :

```
Select distinct
s.SubscriberKey,
s.JobID,
s.BatchID,
convert(char(19),s.EventDate,20) as SendDate
from [_sent] s
left join [_open] o
on s.JobID = o.JobID and s.ListID = o.ListID and s.BatchID = o.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID and o.IsUnique = 1
left join [_click] c
on s.JobID = c.JobID and s.ListID = c.ListID and s.BatchID = c.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID and c.IsUnique = 1
where
s.JobID = JobID
and (o.SubscriberID is NULL and c.SubscriberID is NULL)
```

I've understand I should change JobId to my email's Job Id but I don't quite understand why this :`(o.SubscriberID is NULL and c.SubscriberID is NULL)` retrieve the number 0 of clicks and emails.
For my example should I do a COUNT of o.subscriberID and c.subscriberID to get my new fields?

EDIT : result of the query with OverWrite property
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry doing this on the fly, but below should get you to where you need. Please keep in mind that this will be a fairly intensive query as it is hitting 3 data views (I would recommend pushing your data views into DEs and then querying them and possibly using a send log instead of the sent data view.)

1. It takes the send audience and limits it to a specific Job ID
2. It joins that send audience with opens and counts each time that subscriber appears inside of open (total number of oopens) - can use the IsUnique field if you want only unique opens
3. Joins the send/open audience with the click audience and counts the subscriber for total number of clicks.

SQL:

```
Select 
s.SubscriberKey,
s.JobID,
s.BatchID,
convert(char(19),s.EventDate,20) as SendDate,
c.[Click],
o.[Open]
FROM (
    SELECT
    sn.SubscriberKey,
    sn.JobID,
    sn.BatchID,
    sn.EventDate
    FROM [_sent] sn
    WHERE JobID = 123456
) s
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SubscriberKey, COUNT(*) as [Open], JobID
    FROM [_Open] op
GROUP BY op.SubscriberKey, op.JobID
) o
ON s.SubscriberKey = o.SubscriberKey
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SubscriberKey, COUNT(*) as [Click], JobID
    FROM [_Click] cl
    GROUP BY cl.SubscriberKey, cl.JobID
) c
ON s.SubscriberKey = c.SubscriberKey
WHERE s.JobID = c.JobID
AND s.JobID = o.JobID
AND s.JobID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help! However when I try to put this query in automation studio , it says : "×
An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Open'." I don't understand why because it seems correct SQL

Comment: The only thing I see is maybe there is no condition for left join ("ON") but maybe I missed something

Comment: I accidentally used WHERE instead of ON. Will edit. I also am going to add brackets to open and click column names to make sure it is not confused by the Open function in SQL.

Comment: You forgot to put the brackets also before the FROM but now it says :  Errors: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

Comment: yeah, I actually made it worse - thats what I get for trying to do it on my phone. I will re-edit this again in a minute when I get back on my laptop.

Comment: This should now work. I checked the syntax and it came back clear - just remember to change 123456 to your actual job ID in the _sent query

Comment: When I run the query I get the error : "Query failed during execution. Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'Test email SQL Activity". And it is not coming from my DataExtension ( it has only 3 records each one is different with 2fields : name and email), I was forced to have a primary key for running this in automation studio (I putted it on the SubscriberKey or JobID and did not work), what should I do?

Comment: With the add or update functionnaity, it doesn't work, however thanks to the overwrite property, I see that only the first subscriber is taken because they shouldn't have the same number of open and clicks (Edited my post above to see what it looks like SubscriberKey is my primaryKey there)

Comment: I found the problem ! The join was on JobId where it should be on subscriber keys